# javascript dropzone remove file

Tags: javascript, dropzone.js

I am trying to use Dropzone to upload an image file. When the file is selected, I have it checking on the server with an ajax request to see if the file already exists. If so, prompt the user if they want to overwrite.

This all works. If they choose OK to overwrite, it happens, if not , it doesn't happen.

My problem is, they choose not to overwrite, the file doesn't clear from the preview pain. I am using this.removeFile(file) but it stays visible.

```
var ImageDropzone = new Dropzone("div#ImageDropzone", { 
                url: "upload.php",
                maxFiles: 1,
                accept: function(file, done) {
                  FileExists(file.upload.filename, function(resp) {

                    if (resp == true)
                    {
                        alertify.confirm("This file already exists. Overwrite?", function (e) {
                            if (e) {
                                alert("Overwrite");
                                return done();                                 
                            }
                            else {
                                alert("Dont overwrite");
                               this.removeFile(file);
                               return done();
                            }
                        })
                    }
                    else                          
                        return done();
                    });
                },
                success: function (file,resp){
                    alert("Result = " + resp);

                    var Obj = JSON.parse(resp);

                    if (Obj.Result == "OK")
                    {
                        alert("OK");
                       // $("#ImageDropzone").hide();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        alert(Obj.Message);
                    }
                }                
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be fine doing `ImageDropzone.removeFile(file)` rather than `this`